# Spring Boot in Maven: "No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am learning Java and Spring Boot (I'm pretty new at programming). I have made a simple API app that I can run from IntelliJ and which responds correctly to requests made to it. Now I want to package it as an executable .jar file so that I can try to have it hosted on a remote server, but the jar file I make doesn't run properly.
The error is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.`

This is a Maven project and I think this is probably a problem with my pom.xml file, but after several hours of trying, I can't figure out what the solution might be. Can someone help me please?

My pom.xml is here: https://github.com/NickRoach/simple-spring-API/blob/main/demo/pom.xml The rest of the project is available there too.

Comment: How you create the executable jar?  Is it via maven? Can you post the commands?

Comment: Yes I can make the executable jar. I do that by setting that as an artifact in IntelliJ

Comment: Solved. Rather than set intelliJ to make the .jar file as an artifact, I gave the command "./mvnw package -DskipTests" in the project directory in gitbash (a mentor gave me this advice). This built the project and the resulting jar file runs and works properly

Comment: Don't forget to add your solution as an the answer and then, when possible, accept it as the correct one ;)

Comment: Thanks, I did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Rather than set intelliJ to make the .jar file as an artifact, I gave the command "./mvnw package -DskipTests" in the project directory in gitbash (a mentor gave me this advice). This built the project and the resulting jar file runs and works properly

Comment: I have also found that I can set IntelliJ to use the Maven build script:
in IntelliJ:
 File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner
 Check the box: "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven"